# Sorting baseadpter using Comparator does not sort

Tags: android, sorting, baseadapter

I have a array list of customised objects (ArrayList).

Each object holds data via getter/setter methods.

I want to add the array list of objects to a baseadpter and display the listview sorted according to the object property called 'PackageName' (the method object.getProccess() will return a String name).

In my customised object class I have implemented Comparable interface with this static method:

```
 // implement Comparable interface to allow sort in aplhapbetically order the adpter sent
         // to the list view

         public static Comparator <ProcessDetails> PacageNameComparator = new Comparator<ProcessDetails>(){

            @Override
            public int compare(ProcessDetails name1, ProcessDetails name2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String nameA = name1.getProcess();
                String nameB = name2.getProcess();

                //accesnding order


                return nameA.compareTo(nameA);
            }




         };
```

When I am setting the adapter (a baseadapter) with the ArrayList of customised objects (ArrrayList ProcessDetails) I first try to sort it:

```
Collections.sort(detailAllsApp, ProcessDetails.PacageNameComparator);

            myAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(detailAllsApp,
                    getApplicationContext(), TaskKillerTabActivity.myTypeface);

            // myAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(detailsApp,
            // getApplicationContext(),
            // TaskKillerTabActivity.myTypeface);
            applicationProcessList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            // allow one item selection at at time only

            applicationProcessList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

However the list returned is never in alphabetical order.
Any feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparators don't really work if you return a comparison of an object to itself. Should be:

```
return nameA.compareTo(nameB);
```

Comment: Second pair of eyes needed cheers...“If I had an hour to solve a problem I'd spend 55 minutes thinking about the problem and 5 minutes thinking about solutions.”